# Facebook App : Who "likes" my application?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Is there a method to obtain, via facebook; a list of all users who liked "your" (or a specific application by id) application? via andy of the available methods, e.g. FQL etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GraphApi to get at this information:

- https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
- https://graph.facebook.com/--user
  id--/likes

Search through the person's likes until you find your application id.

More details here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: ok, however i assume this will only work when you know which users you wish to check against. However, since this data was (in our case) is not being saved via app (to db) when user installs it, we do not have a list of user ids to check against. Is it possible to obtain this list of users who liked the app, when you only have your application id? In other words i'm guessing you need to keep track of these ids at the point a user installs the app... or am i missing the point? :)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook won't tell you who likes your page, just an aggregate total number.

> Note: for privacy reasons it is not possible to query for all users
>   who like a Page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API allows you to query a Facebook Page's "members".  I'm not sure if a member is the same as a liker or fan, but it's worth a shot.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page

For some reason, they limit the result set to 500.